# Can't get text from element in selenium from outside tag?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have the following element

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" align="left" colspan="2">
<b>Zone: </b>
"521X 7SW&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
</td>
```

How do I grab the text containing "521X 7SW"? Everytime I try  the .text command in selenium it only returns "Zone:". If I use the get_attibute("text") command it returns nothing.

I've already selected the element with this command

```
zone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Zone')]")
```

And the text isn't invisible. [Here's a picture](http://funkyimg.com/i/2K45p.png) of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text which you are looking for is not related to '**b**' tag , it's `text()` value of **td tag**. You should find td tag text to get "521X 7SW" value.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@nowraap='nowrap']/text()");
```

**You can optimize xpath of td, as I have used *only displayed HTML in your question*.**

Comment: Thank you so much! I used this code to switch to the parent element               
`zone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Zone:')]/parent::*")`   
 and then I pulled the text and it worked

Answer (score 0):

That is a text node not just text.

You can inject Javascript like this :

```
text_node  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[contains(text(),'Zone: ')]")

data = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", text_node)  
print(data)
```

**text_node** is passed into **Javascript** as `arguments[0]`